# WSO2 EI and XSLT Mediator

Tags: xslt, wso2, wso2-esb

I have a SOAP call returning the following:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getTenantResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2696:TenantInfoBean" xmlns:ax2696="http://beans.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2698="http://exception.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2700="http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2702="http://beans.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2696:active>true</ax2696:active>
            <ax2696:admin>admin</ax2696:admin>
            <ax2696:adminPassword xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:createdDate>2020-03-31T18:05:30.321-03:00</ax2696:createdDate>
            <ax2696:email>erico@mail.com</ax2696:email>
            <ax2696:firstname>erico</ax2696:firstname>
            <ax2696:lastname>mtx</ax2696:lastname>
            <ax2696:originatedService xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:successKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:tenantDomain>dom20.com</ax2696:tenantDomain>
            <ax2696:tenantId>1</ax2696:tenantId>
            <ax2696:usagePlan/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getTenantResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to treat the return through a XSLT Mediator in WSO2 Enterprise Integrator 6.6.0.

Some of the attributes return with the content:

```
xsi:nil="true"
```

I need the my mediator to replace these tags with empty values for my attributes.

My current Mediator is with following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is coming like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getTenantResponse xmlns:ns="http://services.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax2696:TenantInfoBean" xmlns:ax2696="http://beans.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2698="http://exception.common.stratos.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2700="http://api.user.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:ax2702="http://beans.mgt.tenant.carbon.wso2.org/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax2696:active>true</ax2696:active>
            <ax2696:admin>admin</ax2696:admin>
            <ax2696:adminPassword xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:createdDate>2020-03-31T18:05:30.321-03:00</ax2696:createdDate>
            <ax2696:email>erico@skalena.com</ax2696:email>
            <ax2696:firstname>erico</ax2696:firstname>
            <ax2696:lastname>teixeira</ax2696:lastname>
            <ax2696:originatedService xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:successKey xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax2696:tenantDomain>dom20.com</ax2696:tenantDomain>
            <ax2696:tenantId>1</ax2696:tenantId>
            <ax2696:usagePlan/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getTenantResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

As example:

```
<ax2696:successKey xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I need it to become:

```
<ax2696:successKey></ax2696:successKey>
```

I need to do this for most of the attributes not only successKey

Thks

Comment: Can you please post what the expected output is?

Comment: hello Sebastien, please I have updated the content with the current output and what I need it to be. Thks!!

Comment: I don't get how you say that your transformation takes an XML input and turns it into some kind of JSON? When I run your transformation on your input I get and XML output as expected.

Comment: Isn't your question answered? If not, why not?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer**

If you want to remove all @xsi:nil='true'

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil"/>
```

If you want to remove @xsl:nil='true' only on certain nodes

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[local-name(parent::*) = 'originatedService']"/>
```

See an example here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4J4/1

**Original answer**

Not sure I really understand your question. Is this what you are trying to achieve?

Replace

```
  <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil = 'true']" />
```

By

```
  <!-- TEMPLATE #2 -->
  <xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[. = 'true']">
      <xsl:attribute name="nil" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNmC4J4

Comment: I need to replace, for example in my source: <ax2696:originatedService xsi:nil="true"/> for <ax2696:originatedService></ax2696:originatedService> . But there are records where originatedServices is not null ... on these cases I need to show the value

Comment: Update your original question to show a complete example. Can't really help if I can't see what you are working with.

Comment: Sorry for the mess. I have edited the content, ok? Thks

Answer (score 0):

Your template matches any element that has a `xsi:nil="true"` attribute and removes it. If you want to remove only the attribute itself, make it:

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil[. = 'true']" />
```